# How to display a table with a span at its side?

Tags: html, css

I DO NOT understand how all the display things work with css and html... 
I need to have something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <table style="display:inline-table; vertical-align:middle;">...</table> 
   <span style="vertical-align:middle;"><img></span> 
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <table style="display:inline-table; vertical-align:middle;">...</table> 
   <span style="vertical-align:middle;"><img></span> 
</div>
```

I've added an image of my problem. I'd love to have the gold pictures vertical centered at the right side of the table.

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2hnnu1x2ML0/VCWv1_mCcBI/AAAAAAAANPc/zDu3eI-WbmY/w957-h458-no/example.png

I'd be grateful with any help provided

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element.  Use `<div>` and your floats will work.

Comment: Where's the CSS? Basic HTML markup doesn't do anything you're trying to.

Comment: Your updated markup looks even worse.

Comment: hihi, you're right, that was my first try :( Now I've edited ant I cannot get the image and the table vertical aligned within the div... any idea?

Comment: @nanmaniac I've already answered this question, you've mistakenly added the vertical align to the span element rather than the image. Here's a bit [more complex example](http://jsbin.com/betuvu/1/edit) of my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using table in this case, however In order to make `<table>` and the adjacent `<span>` stay at the same line you have to change the `display` type of the table to `inline-table`.

Then give `text-align: center` to the parent `<div>` to center the inline level elements as follows:

```css
div { text-align: center; }

table, span img {
  vertical-align: middle; /* optional */
}

table {  display: inline-table; }
```

```html
<div>
  <table><tr><td>Table #1</td></tr></table> 
  <span><img src="http://placehold.it/50"></span> 
</div>

<div>
  <table><tr><td>Table #2</td></tr></table>
  <span><img src="http://placehold.it/50"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, and it almost work.THANKS!! I know that vertical alignment is tricky to achieve so I'll put a margin-top to the span in order to more or less center it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` or use `display: inline-table` for table to display table and span on same line. And add text-align:center to your div which you wanted to center

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <table></table>
    </div>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <table></table>
    </div>
    <span></span>
</div>


div{
    height:100px;
    width:205px;
}

div.table{
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:block;
}

span{
   display:block;
   height:100px;
   float:right;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: It's work fine on applying display:block property... you can refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5rvxkhty/

Comment: I should add that the table contents are thead, caption, tfoot and tbody. Wheen I put table display block, it messes it up.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is use div tags instead of span. Looks a little messy, but I believe it would get the job done.

```
<div style="display:block;">
     <div style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
       <div> 
            <table></table> 
       </div>
       <div> 
            <img> 
       </div> 
     </div>

     <div style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
         <div>
             <table></table> 
         </div>
         <div> 
             <img>
       </div> 
    </div>
<div>
```

The style applied to the parent tag will also apply to all it's children, unless it is overwritten. The div tags that are holding the images and tables have "display:block;" which would force them to be on separate lines. "inline-block;" will have the two the elements on the same line. You may have to still play with margins, padding, and other style elements to get it exactly how you would like it.

If you haven't yet, you can check out http://www.w3schools.com. They have tons of information on CSS and HTML along with examples.

Comment: I'll give it a try later, Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your span and the code will work. See [JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzanfrz7/1/).

And here is a small demo that explins why inline container didn't center the image: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzanfrz7/2/. The height of the inline box takes into account only height of the text. Turning it into inline-block makes it contain all its content and take the resulting height, which is centered.